# How to avoid updating some packages

Tags: 11.04, update-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prevent updating of a specific package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package)

When using Ubuntu at work I have to untick Facebook and Twitter plugins for Gwibber every time the Update Manager starts (I get 403 - Forbidden).

Is there a way to tell the Update Manager to stop looking for these updates without removing Gwibber?

Comment: Np, you can always disagree ;)

Comment: Not in this case, that's what I was looking for :)

Comment: I have noticed that using Synaptic Package Manager hides packages from the Update Manager while using the `dpkg --set-selections` makes the packages appear unticked! I love the latter!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is called *[Pinning](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto):* and can done in several ways. From the link...

> **Introduction to Holding Packages**
>
> Holding a package basically means you're telling the package manager to keep the current version no matter what. This is useful if more recent version of a currently working program breaks after an update.
>
> The following will describe the process of actually holding the package, there are several options to accomplish this<...>

The manual method is the easiest if it is just a few packages...

```
sudo -i 
echo {package_name} hold | dpkg --set-selections
```