# Problem of sound with HD channels using Kaffeine (media player for TV TNT tuner)

Tags: sound, tv-tuner

To watch TV on my computer, with my TV tuner, I installed [**Kaffeine**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/kaffeine/) [image]

I had no problem with this software on Ubuntu 12.04.
But with Ubuntu 14.04, and Kaffeine V1.2.2-2 the result is:

- non HD channels are running ok,
- video of HD channels is ok but not the sound => it makes horrible noise

<sub>Note that I installed Kaffeine V1.2.2-2 from Ubuntu Software Centre [image]</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution from this [French Ubuntu Forum](http://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?pid=17023001#p17023001).

### The solution is to install the latest version of **Kaffeine V1.3**

This version is not yet available in Ubuntu Software Centre [image] so we need to install it [**from Git repository**](https://launchpad.net/~mtron/+archive/ubuntu/kaffeine-git)

1) Install some prerequisite packages:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get install git
sudo apt-get install cmake
sudo apt-get install kdelibs4-dev
sudo apt-get install kdelibs5-dev
sudo apt-get install libxss-dev
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev
sudo apt-get install qt5-default
sudo apt-get install libvlc-dev
```

2) Get sources of Kaffeine V1.3

```
git clone git://anongit.kde.org/kaffeine
cd kaffeine
gedit CMakeLists.txt
```

3) In row 12 of file `CMakeLists.txt`, add this `add_definitions(-fPIC)`

```
...
11 : add_definitions(${KDE4_DEFINITIONS})
12 : add_definitions(-fPIC)
13 : if(STRICT_BUILD)
...
```

4) now compile and install

```
cmake . -DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/qmake-qt4
make
sudo make install
```

=> Now you should have Kaffeine V1.3 and no more problem with your HD channels.

5) And to avoid that you get back to Kaffeine V1.2 every time you do an update [image], you can hold Kaffeine package like this (from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/99013/32413))

```
sudo -i 
echo kaffeine hold | dpkg --set-selections
```